# Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): adminList is not iterable

Tags: node.js, reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-router

I am trying to register admin in my database, but it keeps throwing error after registering the admin in my database; Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): adminList is not iterable

````
    const request = axios.post(`/api/admin/register-admin`,admin)

    return (dispatch) =>{
        request.then(({data})=>{
            let admins = data.success ? [...adminList, data.admin]:adminList // this is where the error is pointing at
            let response = {
                success:data.success,
                admins
            }
            dispatch({
                type:'ADMIN_REGISTER',
                payload:response
            })
        })
    }
} ```
````

Comment: well, what is `adminList` in that context?

Answer (score 0):

You're using `adminList` but I don't see where this variable is defined. I assume, you forgot to define it, therefore it's `undefined` and when you try to spread `undefined` as `[...undefined]` you get this error.

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand what the error is: This error comes in when you want to iterate over something which has not already implemented the iterable protocol. For ex:

```
var obj = { 'France': 'Paris', 'England': 'London' };
for (let p of obj) { // TypeError: obj is not iterable
    // …
}
```

And how can you make it iterable protocol:

```
Instead you have to use Object.keys or Object.entries, to iterate over the properties or entries of an object.

var obj = { 'France': 'Paris', 'England': 'London' };
// Iterate over the property names:
for (let country of Object.keys(obj)) {
    var capital = obj[country];
    console.log(country, capital);
}

for (const [country, capital] of Object.entries(obj))
    console.log(country, capital);
```

In your case, I don't see adminList and where it is declared and assigned any value. So, I think you want to iterate over the object and assign it to array. This is not possible with spread operator, you can't spread the object into array.

```js
var obj = {'test': 'test 1'};
var obj1 = {...obj};
console.log(obj1);

var arr = [1, 2, 3];
var arr1 = [...arr];
console.log(arr1);

// now when you spread obj to array or vice versa you wil get the type error

var arr1 = [...obj];
var obj2 = {...arr1};
```

For more information you should read [this](https://livecodestream.dev/post/how-to-use-the-spread-operator-in-javascript/).

Comment: Thank you, I've already figured it out. I was iterating and not implementing, hence the error.